# get the last sunday and saturday's date in python

Tags: python, date, datetime

Looking to leverage `datetime` to get the date of beginning and end of the previous week, sunday to saturday.

So, if it's 8/12/13 today, I want to define a function that prints:

`Last Sunday was 8/4/2013 and last Saturday was 8/10/2013`

How do I go about writing this?

EDIT: okay, so there seems to be some question about edge cases. For saturdays, I want the same week, for anything else, I'd like the calendar week immediately preceding `today`'s date.

Comment: Why is last Sunday 8/4/2013 and not 8/11/2013? Please specify *exactly* the behavior that you want.

Comment: I've tried messing around with `timedelta`, but I can't get the offset right.

Comment: Please don't use ambiguous English words like "last" in trying to specify this. You need to be 100% clear. I mean, haven't you had a conversation in your life of the form "the party is *next* Friday?" "it's Monday right now, do you mean four days from now, or do you mean eleven days from now?"

Comment: if it's 8/12 and I'm asking for `8/4` and `8/10` it should be clear what I'm asking for.

Comment: @fox: I *said* 8/10. **Clearly** it's not clear given that you have no answers yet and people asking for you to clarify, and *four* downvotes.

Comment: Oh, I get it, OP is assuming Sunday is the first day of the week?

Comment: yeah sorry, I am assuming that.

Answer (score 61):

[datetime.date.weekday](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) returns `0` for Monday. You need to adjust that.

Try following:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> today
datetime.date(2013, 8, 13)
>>> idx = (today.weekday() + 1) % 7 # MON = 0, SUN = 6 -> SUN = 0 .. SAT = 6
>>> idx
2
>>> sun = today - datetime.timedelta(7+idx)
>>> sat = today - datetime.timedelta(7+idx-6)
>>> 'Last Sunday was {:%m/%d/%Y} and last Saturday was {:%m/%d/%Y}'.format(sun, sat)
'Last Sunday was 08/04/2013 and last Saturday was 08/10/2013'
```

If you are allowed to use [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil import relativedelta
>>> today = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> start = today - datetime.timedelta((today.weekday() + 1) % 7)
>>> sat = start + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=relativedelta.SA(-1))
>>> sun = sat + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=relativedelta.SU(-1))
>>> 'Last Sunday was {:%m/%d/%Y} and last Saturday was {:%m/%d/%Y}'.format(sun, sat)
'Last Sunday was 08/04/2013 and last Saturday was 08/10/2013'
```

Comment: Use datetime's isoweekday() instead of weekday() to get standard weekday numbers (0 for sunday, 1 for monday, etc.)

Comment: @jderefinko `isoweekday()` returns 7 for Sunday.

Comment: `today = datetime.date(2019, 6, 29)` returns `2019-06-16` for last Sunday when it should be `2019-06-23`

Comment: @Gi0rgi0s, If I understood right, OP want sunday, saturday of previous week, not the last Sunday.

Comment: If you want last Sunday and last Saturday, then change relativedelta.SA(-1) to relativedelta.SA(0) and relativedelta.SU(-1) to relativedelta.SU(0))

@falsetru - I think this is a brilliant solution

Answer (score 13):

I found the best answer from [here](http://blog.tuxcoder.com/2011/9/14/python_date_calculations/) working fine in my case

try this

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import time

def last_day(d, day_name):
    days_of_week = ['sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday',
                        'thursday','friday','saturday']
    target_day = days_of_week.index(day_name.lower())
    delta_day = target_day - d.isoweekday()
    if delta_day >= 0: delta_day -= 7 # go back 7 days
    return d + timedelta(days=delta_day)
```

Comment: unfortunately the link is down but here's an example call: last_day(datetime.today(), 'sunday')

Comment: @kartheek Could you elaborate what the arguments are? As the link is broken?

Answer (score 8):

```
from datetime import date

def satandsun(input):
    d = input.toordinal()
    last = d - 6
    sunday = last - (last % 7)
    saturday = sunday + 6
    print date.fromordinal(sunday)
    print date.fromordinal(saturday)
```

Note that this seems to survive all of your cases:

```
>>> satandsun(date(2013, 8, 10))
2013-08-04
2013-08-10
>>> satandsun(date(2013, 8, 11))
2013-08-04
2013-08-10
>>> satandsun(date(2013, 8, 12))
2013-08-04
2013-08-10
>>> satandsun(date(2013, 8, 13))
2013-08-04
2013-08-10
>>> satandsun(date(2013, 8, 14))
2013-08-04
2013-08-10
>>> satandsun(date(2013, 8, 15))
2013-08-04
2013-08-10
>>> satandsun(date(2013, 8, 16))
2013-08-04
2013-08-10
>>> satandsun(date(2013, 8, 17))
2013-08-11
2013-08-17
```

Answer (score 6):

When I was dealing with this I came with this solution:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def prior_week_end():
    return datetime.now() - timedelta(days=((datetime.now().isoweekday() + 1) % 7))

def prior_week_start():
    return prior_week_end() - timedelta(days=6)
```

So OP could use it as:

```
'Last Sunday was {:%m/%d/%Y} and last Saturday was {:%m/%d/%Y}'.format(prior_week_start(), prior_week_end())
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.today()    
sat_offset = (d.weekday() - 5) % 7  
saturday = d - datetime.timedelta(days=sat_offset)    
print("Last Saturday was on", saturday)
sun_offset = (d.weekday() - 6) % 7
sunday = d - datetime.timedelta(days=sun_offset)
print("Last Sunday was on", sunday)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> today = date.today().toordinal()
>>> lastWeek = today-7
>>> sunday = lastWeek - (lastWeek % 7)
>>> saturday = sunday + 6
>>> print "Last Sunday was %s and last Saturday was %s" % (date.fromordinal(sunday), date.fromordinal(saturday))
Last Sunday was 2013-08-04 and last Saturday was 2013-08-10
```

Comment: This fails the OP's spec for 8/10/2013.

Comment: Yes, intentionally. It's a silly spec. What OP actually wants (distinct from what he asked for) is the beginning and end of the immediately prior week. If the current time is 11:30AM on Saturday, his odd addendum requires the *current* week, not the *prior* week.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
last_sat = today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday()+2)
last_sun = today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday()+1)
```

*today* is set to UTC, feel free to use your preferred way.

Answer (score 2):

Following code works for me:

```
    today = datetime.date.today()
    last_sunday_offset = today.weekday() + 1  # convert day format mon-sun=0-6 => sun-sat=0-6 
    last_sunday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=last_sunday_offset)
```

Note: Above I have taken normal weekday(0 for Monday) but in isoweekday Monday would be 1.
For more details you can check out **weekday() and isoweekday()** method of **python built-in package datetime.py**:

````
    def weekday(self):
        "Return day of the week, where Monday == 0 ... Sunday == 6."
        return (self.toordinal() + 6) % 7

    # Day-of-the-week and week-of-the-year, according to ISO

    def isoweekday(self):
        "Return day of the week, where Monday == 1 ... Sunday == 7."
        # 1-Jan-0001 is a Monday
        return self.toordinal() % 7 or 7```
````

Answer (score 1):

this is what i did:

```
import datetime


def what_date_was_last(day_of_the_week):
    today = datetime.date.today()

    last_seven_dates_from_yesterday = {}
    mod_count = -1
    for i in range(7):
        tdelta = datetime.timedelta(mod_count)
        mod_count -= 1
        date = today + tdelta
        last_seven_dates_from_yesterday[date.weekday()] = date

    days_of_the_week_dict = {
        "mon": 0,
        "tue": 1,
        "wed": 2,
        "thu": 3,
        "fri": 4,
        "sat": 5,
        "sun": 6,
    }       
    answer=last_seven_dates_from_yesterday
         [days_of_the_week_dict[day_of_the_week]]
    return answer
```

so now i can run..

```
what_date_was_last("sun")
```

or any day of the week

```
what_date_was_last("tue")
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this simply by using pyhton's nthBday package**

```
# First install the required package
!pip install nthBday


# Import the package
import nthBday as nb

# Lets create the function
def function_(month,year):
  return 'Last Sunday was {:%m/%d/%Y} and last Saturday was {:%m/%d/%Y}'.format(nb.last_sun(month,year), nb.last_sat(month,year))

# Test this function
function_(8,2013)
```

***Output:*** 'Last Sunday was 08/25/2013 and last Saturday was 08/31/2013'

Answer (score -1):

This works for my purposes (I have to run a script every Monday), so I just count the days backward.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

prev_sun = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=8)
prev_sun = prev_sun.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

prev_sat = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)
prev_sat = prev_sat.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Hope that helps keep things nice and simple.