# How to avoid fetching data everytime in flask

Tags: python-3.x, oop, flask, global-variables

Hi I have a Python Flask project with following route.

```
@app.route("/results")
def fetch_results():
    today = date.today()
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    results = cursor.execute(f'select * from table where date >= {today} - INTERVAL 7 DAY
                              AND date < {today} ')
    if results <= 0:
        return None
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template("index.html", data = data)
```

I have one more function that sends mail on every sunday with the contents of index.html
Now I want the index.html to display the results that is sent in mail for the next 7 days until new mail is sent. Whenever '/results' is called it should not fetch data. How to do this without using global variables?

Comment: Sounds like you want the send mail job to be the one that creates the html then just have a static route that points to that html code such that viewing the URL will just show the html that the send mail function created

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want something like that. Do you know how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly looking for a redis (in-memory database) with caching

redis keeps the return value for this function active, and caching will prevent to refresh those values for a duration (you can set it to 1 week)

However, you can also do this in code by determining the date of "the most recent sunday" and use this date every time instead of "today"

so when a user checks the route on Friday (the 12th), the query will still check the results for last Sunday (the 7th)

here's a related question about getting the most recent day of the week
[get the last sunday and saturday's date in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200530/get-the-last-sunday-and-saturdays-date-in-python)

I recommend doing this instead of global variables from a different route or a complicated cache, because that isnt its primary use case, and it will cause mismatches if the cache is not refreshed for more than 7 days (results will  start drifting)

Comment: This will still connect to database and query the results from last sunday for every route called. I want to avoid fetching data everytime a route is called.

Comment: If you want to avoid fetching the data, then you should cache the data using the redis in-memory database and the cache.memoize decorator set to 1 week