# How to get dates for => recent friday,friday of last week , friday of 2nd last week,friday of 3rd last wk ,friday of nth last wk from a single code?

Tags: python, datetime

How to get dates for => recent friday,friday of last week , friday of 2nd last week,friday of 3rd last wk ,friday of nth last wk from a single code?

Comment: This has been answered - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200530/get-the-last-sunday-and-saturdays-date-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get last Friday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686991/how-to-get-last-friday)

Comment: these where helpful thank you  the problem is kind of theoretically solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im getting this from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686991/how-to-get-last-friday) you could use the dateutil library:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, FR
lastfriday = datetime.now() + relativedelta(weekday=FR(-1))
print(lastfriday) # lastfriday is a datetime element, do anything with it
```

to get 2nd last do -2, for 3rd -3 and so on

Comment: hey Avi i am geting this error  --AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: yeah, sorry abt that. I fixed it now. hope its not to late

Answer (score 0):

Without `dateutil`, you could do it this way:

```py
import datetime
import calendar

now = datetime.datetime.now()

dow = now.weekday()

print('Today is {0}, {1}.'.format(calendar.day_name[dow], now.strftime('%m/%d/%y')))

# Find the nearest Monday.
monday = -dow if dow < 4 else 7-dow

# Use the previous week's Friday if today is a Friday.
friday = 4 - (7 if dow == 4 else 0)

last_friday = (now + datetime.timedelta(days=monday+friday, weeks=-1)) 

print('The date last Friday was {0}.'.format(last_friday.strftime('%m/%d/%y')))

for weeks_ago in range(2, 5):
    last_friday = (now + datetime.timedelta(days=monday+friday, weeks=-weeks_ago)) 
    print('The date {0} Fridays ago was {1}.'.format(weeks_ago, last_friday.strftime('%m/%d/%y')))
```

Comment: when i gave  
now = ## tomorow date, saturday

then it prints 

The previous Friday is -8 days ago.

it should be 
The previous Friday is -1 days ago.

Comment: I found and fixed the problem.  Try it again.