# Python get date of the last Sunday from a datetime input

Tags: python

I have an epoch timestamp and i've created a datetime from it:

```
import datetime
epoch = 1614965596103
dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch/1000)
```

I would like to obtain the date of the previous Sunday.

However, if the datetime object represents a Sunday, I would like to return the same date.

What is the simplest way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200530/get-the-last-sunday-and-saturdays-date-in-python):

```
idx = (dt.weekday() + 1) % 7
sun = dt - datetime.timedelta(days=idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `timedelta`

```py
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

epoch = 1614965596103
dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch/1000)

if dt.weekday() != 6:
    deltadays = 6 - dt.weekday()
    dt += timedelta(weeks=-1, days=deltadays)

print(dt)
```

`dt` will remain the current date if it is a Sunday, else it will become the **previous** Sunday.

Wrap it up into a function:

```py
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def sundayGetter(epoch):
    dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch/1000)
    if dt.weekday() != 6:
        deltadays = 6 - dt.weekday()
        dt += timedelta(weeks=-1, days=deltadays)
    return dt

print(sundayGetter(1614454173000)) #Sat 27 Feb 2021
```

**Output:**

```py
2021-02-21 19:29:33
```