# Get the date of last Sunday in another column for current date in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

For my python dataframe, I want another column to be created which will have the last sunday for the current week of the date when the code is run. Week starts from Sunday. For ex my dataframe looks like :

```
ID      Process     
1       Manual
2       Semi
3       Automatic
```

Now say, I have run the code today which is: 8/27/2021. Last Sunday for the current week according to today's date is 08/22/2021. so my dataframe will look like :

```
ID      Process     Last Sunday   
1       Manual      08/22/2021
2       Semi        08/22/2021
3       Automatic   08/22/2021
```

Last Sunday will change every time based on the date I run the code on. However, if I am running the code on the Sunday , it should give me the date of that Sunday since my week starts from Sunday.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get the last sunday and saturday's date in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200530/get-the-last-sunday-and-saturdays-date-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deriving from [*get the last sunday and saturday's date in python*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18200686), you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
df['Last Sunday'] = (datetime.now()
                     -timedelta(days=((datetime.now().isoweekday() + 1) % 7))
                     ).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway  but 08/21/2021 is not the Sunday of the current week. In fact, its Saturday. I am trying to modify the code a bit.

Comment: So I have removed +1 from the code and its working.  Thank you.

Comment: @mightyknows it might depend on the locale? glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.to_datetime` with `pd.Timedelta`

```
>>> df['Last Sunday'] = (pd.to_datetime('now') - pd.Timedelta(days=((pd.to_datetime('now').dayofweek - 1) % 7))).date()
>>> df
   ID    Process Last Sunday
0   1     Manual  2021-08-24
1   2       Semi  2021-08-24
2   3  Automatic  2021-08-24
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but 08/24/2021 is not the Sunday of the current week. In fact, its Tuesday.